# Implementing a composite pattern using MVC/Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns, backbone.js, composite

My webapp has a composite structure i.e. each Category collection can contain a mixture of individual Items and other Categories as its rows/nodes/children (not sure of the correct terminology here). In actual fact, it's a little bit simpler than that as each collection is represented by a model, Category, so essentially each Category collection has both Item models and Category models as its children.

In general is this an advisable way to implement this structure using MVC? More specifically, in Backbone.js is it possible for a collection to have a model factory (taking the json and calculating which model to generate based on the json's structure) instead of a static model property?

Comment: In short, I'd say, "I don't see why not", but I'm curious what others might say.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're receiving a Category/Items list in JSON that looks something like this...

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'My 1st Category',
    'children': [
        {
            'id': 2,
            'name': 'My 2nd Category',
            'children': []
        },
        {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'An Item',
            'price': 109.99
        }
    ]
}
```

Backbone.js doesn't have anything out of the box that supports multiple models in a collection, but it also doesn't have any restrictions on the types of models you put in a collection.

Specifying the model type in the collection definition only does one thing, it lets Backbone know what model type to create if you pass raw JSON to the collection instead of a `Backbone.Model` object.  If you add an `Item` model to a collection that already contains a few `Category` Models, Backbone will have no problem popping it into the models list; it doesn't do any type checking.

So with that in mind, you can use just about everything the collection offers except pass it raw JSON; you'll need to handle that yourself.  So your choices are to either build up your models beforehand, making them into `Backbone.Model` objects, or create something that'll do the parsing for you.

For the second option, the parser, I'd suggest passing a special variable to the collection that contains your raw JSON, then handling that in your `initialize` function.  Here's an example:

```
var CategoryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(m, models) {
        _.each(models, function(model) {
            var modelObject = null;
            if (model.price !== undefined) {
                modelObject = new Item(model);
            } else {
                modelObject = new Category(model);
            }

            this.add(modelObject);
        }, this);
    }
});
```

So it is a little hacky, but you determine the type of model based on if it has a specific field (`price` in my example), create the model object, then add that to the collection.

You'd then call it this way:

```
var myCollection = new CategoryCollection([], myJSON);
```

Notice you have to pass an empty array as the first argument since that's how'd you normally pass a set of models to the collection.

Later on when using the collection, you can determine if you're dealing with an `Item` or `Category` using a simple `instanceof` check:

```
_.each(myCollection.models, function(model) {
    if (model instanceof Item) {
        console.log("It's an Item! Price: ", model.get("price"));
    } else {
        console.log("It's a Category!");
    }
});
```

Comment: neat idea to use the options parameter to smuggle in the raw data.

Comment: Haha thanks.  I thought that'd be easier than hacking the Backbone.js source itself. I guess to clean it up you could always create a wrapper class that you only pass your JSON to which in turn creates and returns the collection for you.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to hijack/wrap a few other collection methods too, mainly as internally Backbone.Model expects ids to be unique e.g I'd need to adapt id so it either accepts a key value pair {modelType: id}, or the same reduced to a formatted string.

Comment: Ahh you're right, more hacking required. I guess another approach to avoid all of this would be to have 2 collections within the Category model itself, one for categories and one for items.  You then wouldn't need a custom collection-- all of your parsing logic would be in the model. I could write up another answer if you'd like a longer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I have done it before. I think this links could help you: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-model

Here is one of the main scripts I used for my project: https://gist.github.com/b65893e0c2e3c46d3dc1

Comment: I can't really figure out what you've done in that gist. All I can see are models of one type, TransactionDetail, being added to the collection, wehn I want the freedom to add two kinds. Since posting this question I started to edit Backbone to try and get what I needed, but it has inbuilt unique ID rules for teh collection, so I think I will need to create some bridging model with ids generated from model type and id. But i'm still interested to see if there's a better way

Comment: I see. Well, I hope you can find the way to do it like you need it though. Best of lucks.

Comment: He is right, you can give a factory function as model property of your Collection class... http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-model

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simply achieved by overwriting the built in public methods [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) and [toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) used internally by backbone when retrieving and saving model's data.

Firstly when you retrive the Model from the database you should overwrite the model's `parse` method to create models representing given items from your example.

Then on save the `toJSON` method is used to serialize the data back to what the server can understand - there you'd just call the `toJSON` method on each item's Model to serialize it to a format that backend will recognize. If you look at the code for `Backbone.sync` you will see that the model always gets serialized using the toJSON if no custom data is passed.

Let me know if you needed more detailed info though I believe you should be able to pick it up from here!

Comment: I think that could form part of a solution, but there are other methods that may need tweaking too e.g Backbone.Collection._prepareModel (for my app I can just make sure I never pass in raw json to Collection.add (which calls .prepareModel internally), but it'd be nice to have a solution which can handle using Collection.add for an array of jsons

Comment: I believe that overwriting the Model's `set` method to parse attributes/JSON passed could do the trick - it's called when model is initialized to set the passed attributes extend by defaults both when using `new Model({...})` and when using `collection.add([{...},...])`

Comment: ps. we've learned the hard way in spite of the quickly approaching release of backbone 0.9 that modifying private API methods can backfire on you :) that's why i'd try to stay away from messing with `_prepareModel` it shouldn't go away - but for example `_add` and `_remove` are gone now in master branch of backbone

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a Factory Method pattern for model creation in backbone's Collections. Assuming the data structure suggested in [@kpeel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8944961/170132), you could define

```
// Factory method
var CategoryOrItemFactory = function(data, options) {
    if (data.children) {
        return new Category(data, options);
    } else {
        return new Item(data, options);
    }
};

// Model definitions
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.children = new Children(this.get("children"));
    }
});

var Children = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CategoryOrItemFactory
});
```

You would then create your root item (Category) and have the complete data structure created:

```
// create the root item
var rootItem = new Category(rawData);
```

Access a Category's children its `children` property, e.g.

```
  rootItem.children.get(2).get("name");
```

Here is a [jsFiddle with the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/green/aAfvP/) to play with.

Comment: But there are still various issues to do with synching with the database and Backbone.Collection's expectation of unique ids (e.g. get doesn't work properly http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Dbr/ - it returns the second matching result and ignores the first). I notice in your example that Category extends model rather than Collection, and I'm not sure how comfortable I am with this too, although to avoid having to do widespread refactors of backbone.js maybe I'll have to create some kind of hybrid class with a collection as a property, rather than inheriting from collection

Comment: Well, I have tried to answer your question: whether it is possible to have a model factory (yes). Your Categories must have properties (e.g. an ID) so they need to be derived from Model (e.g. a Collection's `get` does something else than the method of a Model). About the IDs: how do you identify your data entries in the first place? I guess it should be possible to create a meaningful and unique identifier quite easily?

Comment: And as for syncing: it should be possible to set the correct `url` values both for Items/Categories and Children. How do you sync your data? Could you show us some of real data?

Comment: The app is as yet unbuilt so I can't show you any code, but the ids problem is a fundamental problem with implementing a model factory - it needs to ensure items in the collection have unique ids, which will probably be different to the original data e.g. {id:1, modelType: item} would go to something like {id:item1, _origId: 1}, so then the Collection's syncing, adding, removing etc... methods will need to be altered to process/unprocess ids in a similar way

Comment: I see, but these IDs should be no big problem? Enumerate and/or construct from parent IDs...

Comment: It's simple to rewrite the ids, but what I'd like to avoid is having little bits of custom code dotted all around Backbone.js in order to interpret the ids. I'm gonna try @Tom_Tu 's suggestion below, of overriding the parse and toJSON methods on my collection as it looks like it might work